# JavaScript RegExp issue with lists

Tags: javascript, html, regex, frontend, html-lists

people!
I have an issue where I don't know how I can replace my text with ul, li tags.

Here it is:
I have such text, for example:

```
let text = "Du bist der beste Mensch";
```

I need to convert the "der beste Mensch" part into:

```
<ul>
 <li>der<li>
 <li>beste<li>
 <li>Mensch<li>
</ul>
```

So the general output should be:

Du bist

- der

  beste

  Mensch

I tried to use regular expressions and ended up with:

```
text.replace(/(?:^|\n)- (\S+)/g, '<li>$1</li>');
```

If I put `<ul><li>$1</li></ul>`, it, of course, would give me those words boxed in both ul and li tags which is not what I wanted.

Comment: I think this is not a task to do with a RegExp.

Comment: can i suggest you a way without regex?

Comment: Teemu, I'm just trying to make my own text editor with, you know, wrapping text into ** ** to make it bold or _..._ to make it italic. And regulars expressions helped me good. So I thought that probably they can help me with lists too...

Comment: armin yahya, yes, please

Comment: Well, RegExps can do a lot of stuff, but this seems to be beyond them. Can you clarify, do you want to create live markup, or do you want to get the list as text to show in the text editor? Also, how are you identifying where to actually start the list? It starts from "der" in the example, but if this is for a text editor, the text can have almost whatever content.

Comment: So, basically, I'm trying to achieve something like they have on github where you click on "list" icon and get "- " symbol showing your list began. And I want to parse a text identifying all "- asdasdas" strings, consequentially going and separated by a new line.
So I want from this 
- Some line
- Some line
 
Get this:
<ul>
<li>Some line</li>
<li>Some line</li>
</ul>
Then the result is pasted into div-block and automatically converted into dots (just how html shows lists)

Comment: You can use split for that, for example you have let text = "- Some line - Some line". you can do: let txt_arr = text.split("-"). This will split your text with a given delimiter that you'll pass on the argument which is the dash ("-"), and will convert it to an array. So next, just loop your txt_arr variable and render the list inside the <ul id="some-id"> elements, something like: txt_arr.forEach(e => document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML = `<li>${e}</li>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the format of the original text:

```
Du bist 
- der
- beste
- Mensch
```

You can nest the `replace` into 2 steps:

1. Replace the entire list inside of `<ul>` tag
2. Replace each list item inside of `<li>` tag

```js
const text = `Du bist 
- der
- beste
- Mensch
`;

const result = text.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n+)- [^\n]+)+/g, 
  list => `<ul>${list.replace(/(?:^|\n+)- ([^\n]+)/g, '<li>$1</li>')}</ul>`
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think I need to learn regular expressions in JS more. Thank you a lot!